# Open As2 server for receiving files

Tags: java, spring-boot, actionscript-2

I have checkout openAS2 server but i am unable to test receive messages where i can configure receiving url and what will be the params of it.
Can someone please help me on this ?

Comment: this is the source where i checkout openAS2 server
https://sourceforge.net/projects/openas2/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.